# Unable to cast COM Object to class type

Tags: c#, exception, uwp, com, runtimeexception

I am making a library management software. I have separated management of database to a separate c# library 'DataAccessLibrary'. It contains DataAccess.cs:

```
public static event MyDelegate Event_AddBook;

    public static void InitializeDatabase()
    {
        using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection("Filename=MyBooks.db"))
        {
            db.Open();

            //Not necessary
        }
    }

    public static void AddBook(Book book)
    {
        Event_AddBook.Invoke(book);

        using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection("Filename=MyBooks.db"))
        {
            db.Open();
            //Not necessary
        }            
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<Book> GetBooks()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Book> books = new ObservableCollection<Book>();

        using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection("Filename=MyBooks.db"))
        {
            db.Open();
            //Not necessary
        }

        return books;
    }
}
```

When a book is added to the database, it invokes the event so that my YourBooks_View class (which displays the books) is notified that a book is added.

(**NOTE: The book is added using a new window.**)

In some other file, I add a book to the database like this:

```
Book b = new Book
{
    Title = title,
    Author = author,
    Publisher = publisher,
    ISBN = isbn,
    Quantity = quantity.GetValueOrDefault(),
    CoverImageLocation = CoverImageUri
};

DataAccess.AddBook(b);
```

The event 'Event_AddBook' is subscribed to by YourBooks class:

```
public sealed partial class YourBooks_View : Page
{
    private BooksViewModel ViewModel { get; set; } = new BooksViewModel();

    public YourBooks_View()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataAccess.Event_AddBook += new MyDelegate(this.GridView_AddBook);
    }

    private void GridView_AddBook(Book book)
    {
        ViewModel.Books.Add(book);
    }
}
```

The code compiles without errors but at run time, when I add the book, this exception is thrown at the line YourBooks_View.GridView_AddBook() :

> System.InvalidCastException
>     HResult=0x80004002
>     Message=Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler' to class type 'System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.
>     Source=System.Private.CoreLib
>     StackTrace:
>      at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW_WinRTDelegate(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget)
>      at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item)
>      at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item)
>      at Bookshelf.YourBooks_View.GridView_AddBook(Book book) in C:\Users\Hemil\source\repos\Bookshelf\Bookshelf\YourBooks_View.xaml.cs:line 54
>      at DataAccessLibrary.DataAccess.AddBook(Book book) in C:\Users\Hemil\source\repos\Bookshelf\DataAccessLibrary\DataAccess.cs:line 44
>      at Bookshelf.NewBook_View.d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Hemil\source\repos\Bookshelf\Bookshelf\NewBook_View.xaml.cs:line 137

I don't know what this means. Is there a way to solve this problem or is there a way to notify the view in some other way.

I am not so good in c#. Forgive me for any mistake or silly question.

**EDIT:** I am using Sqlite Database as provided in Microsoft.Data.Sqlite container.

**EDIT:** I followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases. I am targetting the latest Windows 10 so I did not include Sqlite with my app

**EDIT:** I uploaded the whole source code to a public repository on gitlab here: https://gitlab.com/rahem027/bookshelf2

**EDIT:** I think i should have included BookViewModel source code as well. Well, here it is:

```
public class BooksViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Book> books { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Book> Books
    {
        get { return this.books; }

        set
        {
            this.books = value;
        }
    }


    public BooksViewModel()
    {
        books = DataAccess.GetBooks();
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds a little bit weird but: Can you try to wrap the throwing line in a Task.Run block?

Comment: I didn't get u @TheTanic. Can u show what you mean?

Comment: Wrap the code line, which throws the error in a new Task.Run block, so the execution is performed in another task. I had this error multiple times and this solved it for me! Or specialise that the UI Dispatcher is used! I dont have access to a pc yet so i can't help you with code at the moment

Comment: @TheTanic, this is what I did: `Task.Run(() => ViewModel.Books.Add(book));`. It gives me this error `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  HResult=0x8001010E
  Message=The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))`

Comment: i tried it today and you need the Dispatcher Thread... Sry that i wasn't sure which one is needed. See the answer from Breeze Liu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get this issue is that you update the Main View's `ViewModel` from the New View's thread. When you clicked the `Add` button, the `AddBook` event triggered, this is on the New View's thread, but you update the Main View's `ViewModel` in the `YourBooks_View` class. You should use the [CoreDispatcher.RunAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher#Windows_UI_Core_CoreDispatcher_RunAsync_Windows_UI_Core_CoreDispatcherPriority_Windows_UI_Core_DispatchedHandler_) method to schedule work on the UI thread for the new view.

So just change your code of your `GridView_AddBook` method with [CoreDispatcher.RunAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher#Windows_UI_Core_CoreDispatcher_RunAsync_Windows_UI_Core_CoreDispatcherPriority_Windows_UI_Core_DispatchedHandler_) method to schedule work on the UI thread to add new `Book` object.

Here is the modified code of `GridView_AddBook` method:

```
private async void GridView_AddBook(Book book)
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        ViewModel.Books.Add(book);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the book object you are trying to add to the collection maybe attached to the database, When you perform an operation with the database make sure to **Dispose** its context ( that depends on which db provider you are using ).

So to work around that you can just try to copy the book object to a new instance and put that in your ViewModel Collection like so :

```
private void GridView_AddBook(Book book)
{
    Book b = new Book
    {
        Title = book.title,
        Author = book.author,
        Publisher = book.publisher,
        ISBN = book.isbn,
        Quantity = book.quantity.GetValueOrDefault(),
        CoverImageLocation = book.CoverImageUri
    };
    ViewModel.Books.Add(b);
}
```

Comment: can you please clarify which database provider you are using? and show us some code of how you are accessing the database?

Comment: I updated the question. Do you still have any doubts?

Comment: in your code where u have commented //unnecesary stuff, I think that is the code where you are accessing the database so it is important to see that I just want to make sure you are disposing your dbcontext or wrapping it in a using statement?

Comment: I added some more code to the question. And yes, all of them had a using statement

Comment: your code looks fine, it seems some wierd error in that case,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180816/discussion-between-hemil-and-touseefbsb).

Comment: The problem seems to be related with COM object. I read the error again. That's what I think it is.